# Do While Loop not triggered in cron job (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron

The requirement is to set up a cron job that runs every 4 seconds. Since cron jobs can be executed only in minutes, I decided the trigger my job every minute and within the job, run it several time. Here's the code.

```
public function handle()
{

    $dt = Carbon::now();
    $counter = 60/4; //run the job every 4 seconds
    do {
        //logic goes here
        // add data to database
        time_sleep_until($dt->addSeconds(4)->timestamp);
    } while ($counter-- > 0);
}
```

Cron job is scheduled as in crontab -e

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/dashboard/artisan cronjob:pulldata
```

Job runs perfectly every 4 seconds when I execute it manually with the php artisan command. But, it executes only once a minute when it is triggered by the cronjob from crontab -e.

Comment: Are you looking at the crontab log or the actual result from your 4-second task? Because the crontab will just show you a new entry every 60 seconds.

Comment: Hi, thats a function, and you dont show if/how you call it. It also calls a function that you dont show. Please remember you have to add some context to a question or it remains as big a mystery to us as you

Comment: @MarkWalet, the logic inside the function is to add entries to a table in the database. There has to be 15 entries (each 4 seconds) in one minute, but there is only 1 entry which means the job has executed only once. If I run it manually with artisan command, there are 15 entries in the table.

Comment: to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RiggsFolly, The logic is to add data to the table. will update the question. And the cron job is called from the server (crontab -e). apart from this there's no other context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is have 15 cron jobs, each running every minute, the first is offset by zero seconds, the next is offset by 4 seconds, 8 seconds, 12 and so on

```
* * * * * /path/to/executable param1 param2
* * * * * ( sleep 4; /path/to/executable param1 param2 )
* * * * * ( sleep 8; /path/to/executable param1 param2 )
...
```

Or have a single cron job which chains `(command && sleep 4) &` 15 times

Answer (score -1):

I don't know exactly what goes wrong. But one of the issues could be that a continuous execution of a 1 minute script gets blocked by your server. There is a way to work around this.

What you could do, is create a seperate bash script that calls your artisan command every x seconds. Like suggested in [this Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/802)

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
  /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/dashboard/artisan cronjob:pulldata
  sleep 4;
done
```

And then call this script in your cronjob:

```
*/1 * * * * /var/www/html/dashboard/your-command.sh
```

Comment: You downvoted my response saying that her question was about a bug when your first sentence was "I don't know exactly what goes wrong" and then going further about your preferences. You yourself are not adding any value to the discussion.
Additionally, when answering questions you should provide examples, not just a link.

Comment: You were right. I edited my answer

Answer (score -1):

I would do it like this, since you start the cron job every minute, you have to take into account the time that your actual database logic takes away from the 1 minute on every iteration to prevent overlapping:

```
public function handle() 
{
    $minute = 60;

    do {
       $start = microtime(true);

       // Your Database Logic

       $end = microtime(true);

       sleep(4); 

       $minute = $minute - (4 + (($end - $start) / 60));

    } while ($minute > 0);
}
```

Additionally, you should consider running this just once as a background process, you can do that by adding the ampersand symbol in your console call `php artisan your:command &`, then you could just write it like this, but be sure to clean up every unnecessary variable in your logic in order to prevent high memory consumption:

```
public function handle() 
{
     try {
         $this->process();
     } catch (\Exception $e) {
       // Log your error somewhere
       Log::error($e->getMessage());

       // Re-run process
       $this->process();
     }
}

protected function process() 
{
    while(true) {
         // Your Database Logic
         sleep(4);
     }
}
```

Comment: This is not what the question is about. Dilani experiences a 'bug' where the loop does execute the code every 4 seconds for a minute long, but when called with a cronjob, it isn't. This is just a more fancy way of distributing the 4-second calls.

Comment: My response offers an alternative approach without the cron table, you should have read the whole response.